# Counting distinct texts in a Spark RDD with array objects

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a spark rdd (`words`) which consists of arrays of texts. For an example,

```
words.take(3)
```

would return something like.

```
[ ["A", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["C", "A", "D"] ]
```

Now, I want to find out the total number of texts as well as the unique number of texts. If the RDD had only above 3 records,

```
total_words = 7
unique_words = 4 (only A, B,C,D)
```

Now in to order to get the total, I did something similar like this

```
text_count_rdd = words.map(lambda x: len(x))
text_count_rdd.sum()
```

But I'm stuck on how to retrieve the unique count.

Answer (score 3):

Just `flatMap`, take `distinct` and `count`:

```
words.flatMap(set).distinct().count()
```